# Como indicar que existem n dias

Tags: ortografia

Quando queremos dizer que uma acção ocorreu passados n dias dizemos

> Há n dias isto aconteceu

Mas quando quisermos dizer que alguma coisa tem n dias, por exemplo

> Há n dias no ano em que não se trabalha

Como é que escrevemos a frase acima para indicar o número de dias?

Comment: Não percebi a pergunta. Ambas as frases estão corretas.

Comment: Então mas como consigo fazer a distinção de indicação de tempo e de haver algo?

Comment: @rafaelcpalmeida não sei se entendi direito a sua pergunta.

A diferença entre indicação de tempo e da existência de algo pode aparecer dependendo do contexto, pelo sentido da frase, ou mudando o verbo.

Exemplo: "Há/Faz n dias que isto aconteceu."
"Há/Existem/Tem n dias no ano nos quais não se trabalha"

Comment: Acho que só mesmo pelo sentido da frase.

Comment: "Nos dias 1, 2, 3, 4 e 5 de janeiro não se trabalha", "Nos primeiros cinco dias do ano não se trabalha", "Há pelo menos cinco dias no ano em que não se trabalha" (opções de frases)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A meu ver, a diferença de significado de "Há n dias" nas duas frases é bem clara. O significado só seria semelhante nas duas frases se a segunda delas fosse, por exemplo, "Há n dias não se trabalha" (sem "em que").

De qualquer maneira, eis algumas sugestões caso faça questão de reescrever a frase:

> Não se trabalha em n dias no ano.
>
> Em n dias no ano não se trabalha.
>
> No ano, não se trabalha durante n dias.

Comment: Como é que _há n dias não se trabalha_ causa alguma confusão? A única coisa que isto pode significar é _há n dias que não se trabalha_.

Comment: Para alguém aprendendo português pode não ser tão óbvio, já que esse Há poderia significar Existem e Faz, pois a frase trocando o verbo por Fazer não pode continuar desse jeito "Faz n dias não se trabalha", ou por Existir "Existem n dias não se trabalha", frases nada idiomáticas.

Comment: @Artefacto Pelo menos na minha interpretação, _Há n dias não se trabalha_ tem significado diferente de _Há n dias **em que** não se trabalha_. A primeira frase equivale a _Não se trabalha faz n dias_ (ou seja, desde n dias atrás, e os dias são consecutivos); a segunda, a _Não se trabalha em n dias_ (durante um período qualquer, e os dias não necessariamente são consecutivos).

Comment: Certo. O que estava a dizer é que a única interpretação possível de _há n dias não se trabalha_ é _há/faz n dias **que** não se trabalha_, o que é diferente de _há/existem n dias **em que** não se trabalha_. Mas tu dizes que _há n dias não se trabalha_ pode causar confusão. É aí que discordamos. Tanto quanto vejo, só _há n dias **que** não se trabalha_ pode causar confusão, porque há falantes que suprimem a preposição **em** (estratégia cortadora), i.e., dizem _há/existem n dias **que** não se trabalha_ por _em que_.

Comment: @Artefacto Concordo. Na verdade, expressei-me mal. Editei a resposta.